# Display navbarMenu across complete screen width in Shiny R

Tags: html, css, r, shiny, shinydashboard

I would like to use shiny navbarpage with 4 navbarmenus. these should be displayed horizontally next to each other and be selectable. Only when the screen width across the entire screen is too small to display them,the navbar menus should be displayed in vertical order. How can I display the navbar menus across the entire screen width and prevent them from being displayed vertically earlier? In the two images you can see that the vertical structure is displayed before the entire screen width has been used.

Here is my code:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- navbarPage(
    title=NULL, id = "navBar", collapsible = FALSE,
    navbarMenu("Menu1",
               tabPanel(title = "Panel1", uiOutput('panel1')),
               tabPanel(title = "Panel2", uiOutput('panel2')),
               tabPanel(title = "Panel3", uiOutput('panel3'))),
    navbarMenu("Menu2",
               tabPanel(title = "Panel4", uiOutput('panel4')),
               tabPanel(title = "Panel5", uiOutput('panel5')),
               tabPanel(title = "Panel6", uiOutput('panel6'))),
    navbarMenu("Menu3",
               tabPanel(title = "Panel7", uiOutput('panel7')),
               tabPanel(title = "Panel8", uiOutput('panel8')),
               tabPanel(title = "Panel9", uiOutput('panel9'))),
    navbarMenu("Menu4",
               tabPanel(title = "Panel10", uiOutput('panel10')),
               tabPanel(title = "Panel11", uiOutput('panel11')),
               tabPanel(title = "Panel12", uiOutput('panel12'))),
    
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$panel1 <- renderUI({p("This is panel 1")})
  output$panel2 <- renderUI({p("This is panel 2")})
  output$panel3 <- renderUI({p("This is panel 3")})
  output$panel4 <- renderUI({p("This is panel 4")})
  output$panel5 <- renderUI({p("This is panel 5")})
  output$panel6 <- renderUI({p("This is panel 6")})
  output$panel7 <- renderUI({p("This is panel 7")})
  output$panel8 <- renderUI({p("This is panel 8")})
  output$panel9 <- renderUI({p("This is panel 9")})
  output$panel10 <- renderUI({p("This is panel 10")})
  output$panel11 <- renderUI({p("This is panel 11")})
  output$panel12 <- renderUI({p("This is panel 12")})
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]
[image]